# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, repository-pattern, dapper, unit-of-work

My stored procedure is

```
Create proc [dbo].[InsertPerson]
(
    @LastName   VARCHAR(64),
    @FirstName  VARCHAR(64),
    @Age        INT
)
AS
INSERT INTO Person Values(@LastName,@FirstName,@Age)
```

The save method of the BaseRepository class is as follows:

```
public virtual int Add(string storedProcedure, T entity, IDbTransaction transaction)
 {
    var i = 0;

    try
    {

       if (entity == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("entity", "Add to DB null entity");

       var parameters = (object)Mapping(entity);
       i = _conn.Execute(storedProcedure, parameters, transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

       throw ex;

    }

    return i;
 }
```

The map method is as follows:

```
internal virtual dynamic Mapping(T entity)
{
  return entity;
}
```

The definition of PersonRepository class is as follows:

```
public class PersonRepository:DapperRepository<Person>, IPersonRepository
{
   public PersonRepository(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow) { }

   internal override dynamic Mapping(Person person)
   {
      return new {person.LastName, person.FristName, person.Age };
   }
}
```

My Service class I declared Save method as follows:

```
public void Save(Person person)
{
  try
  {
    string sp = "InsertPerson";
    _repository.Add(sp, person, _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction());
    _unitOfWork.Commit();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {

     throw;
  }
}
```

When I am trying to execute my Save method it shows me following exception:

```
Procedure or function 'InsertPerson' expects parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied.
```

Comment: I would recommend NOT storing a person's age in your database. Age is not a static datapoint, it changes based on the current date. Instead, capture their birthdate and calculate their age when required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is spell mistake in your property name

```
person.FristName
```

it should be

```
person.FirstName
```

So now your mapping function should look like this

```
internal override dynamic Mapping(Person person)
{
      return new {person.LastName, person.FirstName, person.Age };
}
```